# Ошибка с instabot

Tags: python, instagram

Я пытался войти в аккаунт, с помощью instabot, но у меня вылетает ошибка. Вот код:

```
from instabot import Bot
bot=Bot()
bot.login(username="name", password="password")
```

Ошибка:

```
2022-09-15 21:08:33,088 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2022-09-15 21:08:33,089 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2022-09-15 21:08:36,010 - INFO - Logged-in successfully as 'name'!
2022-09-15 21:08:36,010 - INFO - LOGIN FLOW! Just logged-in: True
2022-09-15 21:08:37,258 - ERROR - Error checking for `feedback_required`, response text is not JSON
2022-09-15 21:08:37,258 - INFO - Full Response: <Response [404]>
2022-09-15 21:08:37,258 - INFO - Response Text: <!DOCTYPE html>
```